# Unable to go to else while comparing two strings in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, cordova, phonegap-build

We are trying to get fetch data from database and trying to check IF we find that ID then we will go to the IF condition other wise it will go to ELSE.

Here is how our IF condition looks like this is under a controller:

```
var element = document.getElementById('deviceProperties');

element.innerHTML = 'Device Name: '     + device.model     + '<br />' +
                    'Device PhoneGap: ' + device.cordova + '<br />' +
                    'Device Platform: ' + device.platform + '<br />' +
                    'Device UUID: '     + device.uuid     + '<br />' +
                    'Device Version: '  + device.version  + '<br />';

$rootScope.uid=device.uuid;
$scope.name=device.model;
$scope.phonegap=device.cordova;
$scope.platform=device.platform;
$scope.version=device.version;

$scope.user =$rootScope.uid;

var devicedetail= $http.get(webpath+"devicedetailselect/"+$scope.user);

devicedetail.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    console.log(data[0].uid);

    //This is where i am stuck      

    if(data[0].uid===$scope.user){
        alert("id found");
        $scope.popoverhome = false;
    }
    else{
        //its not coming here in else if it dont find an id
        alert("id not found");
    }
});
```

This `data[0].uid` is coming form database on request. And `$scope.user` is the ID we get from the phone. We are using phonegap to build the mobile application.

But it seems like both the things are getting compared in some another manner & we are not able to figure out.

Comment: any errors in the console? I bet data[0] is undefined...

Comment: No we are getting the data properly. We have tested with console. There is no error in getting the object data.

Comment: Ok is there any priority in POST and GET in angularjs? Because in the same controller i have POST as well.

Comment: If you are using `element.innerHTML` for anything except extreme edge cases when using angular, you are probably doing something wrong.  Also using `$rootScope` is an anti-pattern,  and since you are trying to compare an array element to a value that is assigned from a `$rootScope` property, it is suspect.  However, accessing `data[0]` is also an anti-pattern in this context.  Overall, this code has too many incorrect usage patterns to really decipher what the real issue is.

Answer (score 0):

You are using '===' which compares both content and type of content - 
`data[0].uid===$scope.user`

If `data[0].uid` is a number and `$scope.user` is a string, they are not equal.

To solve this, cast one of them to the other type.

If you can't cast, use the less recommended `==` that compares the content, and not the type.

Comment: OK sure, but we have converted both the things to String() also like this if(angular.equals(String(data[0].uid),String(device.uuid)))

Comment: You have 2 values, which look the same, have the same type, but `===` returns false?

Comment: No its not returning false, that is the problem. I guess "data" is not getting any value

Comment: Try `console.log(data[0].uid===$scope.user, data[0].uid, $scope.user) before the if. What do you get?